# Bootstrap: popover button link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap popover with some customized jquery. Popover function is working fine but **if i have add a button with an external link, its not working.** See the code: **there is two buttons "Button1" for popover & "Button2" for external link.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").tooltip({   
    selector: "[data-toggle='tooltip']",
    container: "body"
  })
  .popover({
    selector: "[data-toggle='popover']",
    container: "body",
    html: true
  });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
       $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
       $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#000;padding-top:50px;">
  <a data-placement="top" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title="">
    Button1
  </a>
  
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Button2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to popover to appear when you user goes over it with their mouse or after the link is clicked? Because I got the last option to work.

Comment: It is working fine as per the expectation. I checked in my local.

Comment: You need to take to the other URL on 2nd button click? or do you want to open the same popup over fr the 2nd button? as like 1st button?

Comment: Actually this jquery used for dismiss popover when we clicked anywhere on the body. I need one button for popover and second button is take to other URL (in a new window). Now its working fine with all browsers except iphone browser.

Comment: @Samir please check it with iphone browser

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some `data-toggle`, `data-placement` syntax's in the second button! Adding these will give the second button the same function as the first button. I have added this to your code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").tooltip({
            selector: "[data-toggle='tooltip']",
            container: "body"
        })
                .popover({
                    selector: "[data-toggle='popover']",
                    container: "body",
                    html: true
                });
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
            if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
                    $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
                    $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
    });</script>

<div class="container" style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#000;padding-top:50px;">
    <a data-placement="top" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title="">
        Button1
    </a>

    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://facebook.com" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title="" target="_blank">Button2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the class to `class="btn"`

Comment: for which button?

Comment: On both buttons. That should resolve the problem for IOS safari. The browser doesn't handle the `btn [extra]` so well. So if you make them both `class="btn"` youre buttons should also work on Sarafi IOS

Comment: Also no need popover on Button2

Comment: Are you using iOS 10.*?

Comment: Have look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/72/

Comment: i hve using iPhone 6+

Comment: I think that there is a problem then with your iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

The stack overflow scripts are blocking your link from opening a new page/redirect. Try this codepen with your code :
http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/oYYbgW

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#000;padding-top:50px;">
  <a data-placement="top" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title="">
    Button1
  </a>

  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Button2</a>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").tooltip({   
    selector: "[data-toggle='tooltip']",
    container: "body"
  })
  .popover({
    selector: "[data-toggle='popover']",
    container: "body",
    html: true
  });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
       $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
       $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the tooltip or the simple link?

Comment: Tooltip. Its does not "dismiss" when we tap anywhere on the body (only in iphone browser)